# Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 valid item, but had 0 Neo4j import csv

Tags: csv, docker, import, neo4j

I am trying to import my database nodes from csv using neo4j-admin importer tool. But each time I run the import command I get this error:

```
Input error: Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 valid item, but had 0
```

I have 2 separate csv files: one with headers only and another one with fields. Here is how my csv file looks like:

```
"event_id:ID", "created", "description", "duration:int", "event_url", "fee_accepts", "fee_amount:float","fee_currency",
    "fee_description","fee_label", "fee_required:int", "group_created", "group_group_lat:float", "group_group_lon:float", "group_id:int",
    "group_join_mode", "group_name", "group_urlname", "group_who","headcount:int","how_to_find_us","maybe_rsvp_count", "event_name", "photo_url",
    "rating_average", "rating_count:int","rsvp_limit:int","event_status", "event_time", "updated", "utc_offset:int", "venue_address_1",
    "venue_address_2", "venue_city", "venue_country", "venue_id:int", "venue_lat:float", "venue_localized_country_name", "venue_lon:float", "venue_name",
    "venue_phone:int", "venue_repinned:int","venue_state","venue_zip:int","visibility", "waitlist_count:int", "why", "yes_rsvp_count:int"
```

And here is the command with which I run neo4j-admin:

```
docker exec -i neo4j_container bin/neo4j-admin import --database import.db --nodes:Event "import/headers.csv,import/events.csv"
```

What may be wrong with the data and how to find out the right away to organize my csv files headers?
I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: You wrote `import/heaSers.csv`.

Comment: The error messages says you are willing to import a file that doesn't exist. Check your paths and be sure you don't make any typos.

Comment: I would recommend adding a docker tag here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist tables from csv into Neo4j using import tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326285/persist-tables-from-csv-into-neo4j-using-import-tool)